# Change HTML table text to text from file

Tags: html, excel

I am currently developing a responsive table, with the hours corresponding to person who is supposed to be on duty. It is something like a work schedule with a person, working at each day from 9am to 7pm. 
The table looks like this

```
 <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thrusday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
</div>  

 <tr>
    <th>9am - 10am</th>        
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>    
</tr>
 <tr>
    <th>10am - 11am</th>        
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>    
</tr>
```

and so on..

Is there a way to put a button, which would choose a file from the computer (excel file for example) and put the corresponding name of the person on duty into the Header?

Comment: Interesting problem. You can perhaps use excel's ability to save the file to CSV and use Javascript to read the data. You would need a well structured excel file for that to work though.

Comment: If you're interested in going in the direction @Brian suggested I would check out [JQuery-CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/).  It helps in handling client side selection and reading of the file.  Look at the source of this [example](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/file-handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to read excel file into html. (So I would say this question is a little bit subjective). I would prefer using [PHP Excel Reader](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader). But you would need (at least) basic knowledge of PHP. 
You can also use Javascript libraries like [JS-XLSX](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) or [JS-XLS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) (support for older xls files). But then again, I don't know what your programming compatibility are. 
There are also examples on each of these GitHub pages. Check them out.